# Create a collection of readonly ref struct

Tags: c#, .net

It is not possible to create an array of a `readonly ref struct` in C# like this:

```
public readonly ref struct SomeStruct {}
SomeStruct[] array = new SomeStruct[4];
```

This throws a compilation error.
How is it possible to store a collection of `readonly ref struct`?

Comment: Rethink your solution. `ref struct`s are stack-only things and array of them means they would go onto heap (unless you `stackalloc` which _might_ be allowed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
    struct SomeStruct
    {
        int Data;
    }

    static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        Span<SomeStruct> buffer = stackalloc SomeStruct[5];

        ref var someData = ref buffer[1];
    }
```

I would caution that you need to profile and make sure you actually need to do something like this.

As others have said you don't put a "ref struct" into a collection instead you put regular structs in the collection and get a "ref" to them so you don't have to copy the data.  Then you control where you allocate them.  Either on the stack if it's not going to cause problems, or you could use memory pools.

Comment: I felt that Span would be the answer but didn't know exactly how! I will weigh your helpful suggestions compared to redesign as Tanveer Badar recommended. I have a graph of hierarchical structs where one struct would hold a 'child' collection of other structs, so one option is to implement hierarchy by flattening it using IDs of type int to indicate parenting, instead of collections, and then everything can be 'ref readonly struct'.

Comment: @user1718625 I would caution against premature optimization.  I'd look at the overall design first and make sure this is what is going to be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, ref struct cannot be stored in a collection. I found this which might be helpful to you.

[Gergely Kalapos](https://kalapos.net/Blog/ShowPost/DotNetConceptOfTheWeek16-RefStruct)